# Tableau has two data tables, how can i make a filter only apply to single data table

Tags: tableau-desktop

I currently have two data tables each linked to a date table.  The data tables are from salesforce.  I can calculate the number of a certain case type per quarter without issue.  I can also calculate the running sum over quarters to show instrument install base increasing.  I want to divide the number of cases per qtr by the install base.  This calculation works, but when I apply a filter to see different types of cases per instrument, the filter impacts the install base as well.  I would like to keep the install base consistent.  I tried different LOD, but no luck.  Any suggestions on filters and LOD and where to place in tableau would be beneficial.

Comment: did you try EXCLUDE LOD ?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a parameter for filtering and then having a calculated field that changes based on parameter values in one table but not in the other table. However, this type of filter would affect all worksheets that use the same data.